# How to allow access to MongoDB in docker only for users?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: "mongo:4.0.4"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=paspaspas
```

But I can connect both `mongo` and `mongo uple -u admin -p paspaspas --authenticationDatabase admin`

How can I allow access only with user & password: `mongo uple -u admin -p paspaspas --authenticationDatabase admin`?

Configure file doesn't help:

```
 volumes:
      - "../mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf"
```

My `mongod.conf`:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

Comment: You can connect `mongo` (without credentials), but it's read-only

Comment: when you connect without credentials, you can't do much except find out which node primary, and authenticate, i.e. you can't list databases, read or write data